# The Law of Demeter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oop, law-of-demeter

I recently posted a question on stackoverflow where I did something to effect of

`@period_registration.period.event`

However, it was suggested that I do something like the following:

```
def event
  period.event
end

@period_registration.event
```

My general sense is that this seems a little heavy-handed. Looking at this previous posting [How do I apply the Law of Demeter to this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950122/how-do-i-apply-the-law-of-demeter-to-this) shows how heavy handed this can become if you did this for every association.

How common of a practice is this in rails? My thought is that even if this is technically the right thing to do, if it isn't a part of the rails culture then it seems that doing this will throw people off. And, more importantly, actually make the code less maintainable as other developers think you're wasting your time with all these helper methods.

Let's say I wanted to impliment this, would @period_registration.event.city, where city is an attribute of event, not a seperate object also violate LoD or would I need to write *ANOTHER* method so I could do: @period_registration.city

Comment: Why you want access to city through period_registration?

Comment: Why you want access to city through period_registration? It is not good design if you did this kind of accessor for every associations. For some associations it's ok, but for all it is realy bad idea.

Comment: It was more of an example than anything else. Let's say you already have @period_registration in a controller and you want to put event.city in your view. How would you do it?

Comment: Good question! In this situation you should use Presenter or Exibit pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, slavish adherence to the Law of Demeter is pretty rare. Still, for associations, this is such a common pattern that it has a shortcut that removes most of the hard work from you:

```
class PeriodRegistration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :period
  delegate :event, :to => :period
end

PeriodRegistration.new.event # calls PeriodRegistration.new.period.event
```

You can read more about this at the [Module#delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) documentation.

At the risk of sounding excessively self-promoting, I have a blog post that discusses this and other ways to try to respect the Law of Demeter, if that's your thing. [Check it out](http://joshsymonds.com/blog/2012/03/28/delegation-when-delegate-just-wont-work/) if you're curious to learn more.

Comment: +1. Concerning your blog post, you've another solution: define methods on the fly from the method_missing. method_missing will only be hit once for a particular method then.